# Bypassing forms input fields to upload unwanted files

Tags: php, security

My website having uploading profile image section for members and i've used the following code.

**Form Code**

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="send" id="send">
    Your Image : <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"/>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP Code `send.php`**

```
$ImageName = $_FILES[pic][name]; 
if(!empty($ImageName) && $_FILES[pic][type] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES[pic][type] == "image/png" || $_FILES[pic][type] == "image/gif" || $_FILES[pic][type] == "image/bmp"){
    $t = time();
    $NewImageName = "$t$ImageName"; // image new name
    copy($_FILES[pic][tmp_name], "users/$NewImageName"); // copy it to directory
} else {
    echo "no upload done";
}
```

But someone by using firefox extension manage to bypass it and uploaded php file
Who uploaded the file to my website sent me message said "you only check for type !" 
and said " i used firefox extension that can fake input fields and passed PHP file ".

***So my question*** how do i protect my image upload form of the above code ? ~ thanks

Comment: you can do protect the folder, even if user upload the php file then php file will not be executed in that upload folder.

Comment: Maybe you need something like: https://github.com/qeremy/image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I don't think that's is the valid format to read $_FILE variable

```
$ImageName = $_FILES[pic][name];
```

You should use

```
$ImageName = $_FILES['pic'][name];
```

Then I think it is improbable that someone can fake a server side check.

Try to hack this, I use a *PATHINFO_EXTENSION* as mentioned in [PHP.net Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$validFormat = array("jpg","JPG","jpeg","JPEG","png","PNG","gif","GIF");    
$path = pathinfo($_FILES['pic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(in_array($path, $validFormat)){
// it's okay
}else{
// Error
}
```

I'm working with this code since I discovered pathinfo a while ago and nobody hack it..

Comment: Thanks, Works perfect and stopped passing unwanted files extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The `"type"` entries in the `$_FILES` array are indeed just values that the client sent. Do not trust them.

files are executed as php not based on the MIME type given by the client (or the MIME type that is recognized from their data), but simply by their extension.

```
$imageName = $_FILES['pic']['name'];

if (isset($imageName)) {
    $ext = pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array(strtolower($ext), array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp')) {
        $t = time();
        $newImageName = $t . basename($imageName);
        copy($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], 'users/' . $newImageName);
    }
} else {
    echo 'no upload done';
}
```

Note the invocation to [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the extension, and [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to avoid [path traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

Comment: Or specifically exclude extensions.  Though inclusive filtering is better than exclusive. ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot, Works as well and didn't passed unwanted files upon testing.